# Objective c dispatch_async crash

Tags: objective-c, nsnotification

**code :**

```
- (void)stopCurrentSessionFromSuite:(NSNotification*)notification{

        isCloseCurrentSession = YES;
        dispatch_async(self.dataSendingQueue, ^{
            CARD8 messageToDisableSession = rpcHostDisableMsg;
            [readerNwriter writeExact:(char*)&messageToDisableSession ofLenght:sizeof(CARD8) secApplied:NO];
        });
        [rpcCaptureMgr stopCaptureSession];

}
```

**Crash :**

> Time Awake Since Boot: 1400 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000070 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
>
> VM Regions Near 0x70:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 000000010871a000-000000010873a000 [  128K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
>   /Applications/RemotePCSuite/*/RemotePCDesktop.app/Contents/MacOS/RemotePCDesktop
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff72de50db
>   _dispatch_continuation_async + 5 1   com.prosoftnet.remotepcDesktop   0x0000000108727fd5
>   -[RPCDesktopAppDelegate stopCurrentSessionFromSuite:] + 104 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff4b7a333c
>   **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff4b7a32cf
>   **_CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff4b7ab92c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12 5
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff4b78e8a3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
>   + 275 6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4b78e668 __CFRunLoopRun + 3128 7   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff4b78d797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487 8   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff4aaa2866 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286 9
>   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff4aaa25d6
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613 10  com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff4aaa2354 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   64 11  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff48d9fa23 _DPSNextEvent
>   + 2085 12  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff49534e6c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044 13  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff48d94831 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 764 14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff48d639d2 NSApplicationMain + 804 15  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff72e0c145 start + 1

Comment: any context information?

Comment: What does breakpointing on `stopCurrentSessionFromSuite` and in the block tell you?

Comment: Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff72f458c7 dispatch_sync_f + 0
1   com.prosoftnet.remotepcDesktop 0x00000001042f8891 -[RPCDesktopAppDelegate stopCurrentSessionFromSuite:] + 104
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff4b0f361c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12

Comment: StopCurrentSessionFromSute, will perform write operation to socket thats all. Modified to sync call same problem. Nt able to understand why it is crashing.

Comment: Working fine removed GCD the Q was getting released. End of operation so not required Q. Working fine now